# Get Mean of a column in data frame

Tags: python-2.7, pyspark

I'm using `pyspark 1.6` and `python 2.7`.
I Have a dataframe, and I wanted to get the mean of a particular column after group by another columns.

`data` is my dataframe

For that I'm doing like below

```
data.registerTempTable('dataframe')
query = 'select mean(Weight) as Weight, b, s from dataframe group by b, s'
df = sqlContext.sql(query)
```

Is there any good way of achieving this result.

Sample Data is like :

```
s       b       Weight
7801    d9b4    0.12911255
7801    6b11    0.128151033
7801    dd1f    0.12791147
7801    c802    0.134295454
7801    1294    0.128722551
7801    4203    0.134276383
7801    accc    0.134290742
7801    aab9    0.129347649
7801    4546    0.126628807
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty trivial to get a mean after grouping: see [pyspark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.groupBy). Try something like what's below, though I believe the sql you defined in the question should also be close to working as is.

```
data.groupBy('b', 's').agg({'Weight': 'mean'})
>>> # [Row(b=u'6b11', s=u'7801', avg(Weight)=0.128151033), ...]
```